# Remove / hide "suggested tags" line, if there are already five tags added

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

Does `suggested tags` line make any sense, if there are already five tags added to question?

Maybe this line should be removed/hidden in case user already provided five tags?

Clicking on suggestions adds more tags only to bump on message, that max five tags are allowed, after submitting such question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes one of the suggestions will be better than one you added before looking at the suggestions.  In that case the suggestions still provide value.

If it's removed at five tags would it reappear if you delete a tag?  If not that could be confusing, but if so you could have it popping in and out as you type/edit tags, which might also be confusing.

Comment: Your argument, expressed in first paragraph is true and good reasoning, however I can't judge, if there is really a large number of user that'll take advantage of "better tags". But, fine. As for your second paragraph -- that's of course purely technical issue. "Suggested tags" line doesn't necessary need to pop in and out, as user type. It can be shown / hidden in an event fired 1-2 seconds after last button typed. Similarly to all the auto-completion widgets, that also don't show up immediately, as user type, but within 1-2 seconds threshold after last character entered.

Comment: @trejder on the second point I was actually raising a *design* question, not an *implementation* question.  What is the correct behavior in that case from the user's point of view?

Comment: As in initial question. "Suggested tags" line should be hidden, if there are five tags already added to question. I don't know, if this is correct behavior, though, but I think this is most reasonable as from my personal point of view.

Comment: And what should happen when the user, while editing, deletes the fifth tag?

Comment: I think, the line should reappear.